# Sending ENQ, id, CR, and LF to Serial Port using C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb, converters

In my app have Converter USB/RS-485.
Have a device with the id 30 connected on this converter.
The manufacturer has informed us that we need to access the device in binary code.
How to send ENQ id CR and LF to this device using C#?

Thank's in advance,
ocaccy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are ASCII codes, the default SerialPort.Encoding is ASCIIEncoding.  So sending a string instead of bytes is not a problem if you prefer it that way:

```
  port.Write(string.Format("\u0005{0}\r\n", id));
```

With the assumption that `id` is encoded as ASCII as well, it isn't clear from the question.

Comment: Thank you, Hans. The device ID is 30. 
port.Write(string.Format("\u0005{0},30,\r\n")); \\this is OK?\\

Comment: 0x30?  That's id = 0.  You completely murdered that Format() call.  Ask your supervisor for some basic training resources.

Comment: The device seems to be getting something with the command:
port.Write(string.Format("\u0005{0}\r\n", 30)); 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ([serial port write method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) ) with a byte array of 5,30,13,10.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[] {
    5,
    30,
    13,
    10
};
sp.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
```

Comment: Thank you dbasnett, I post the result here soon.

Comment: Thank you dbasnett.
 I use the Hans code below, because this working for me. I appreciated your help. 
port.Write(string.Format("\u0005{0}\r\n", 30));

Answer (score 0):

Thanks..
For me without de id Works perfectly.

```
_serialPort.Write("\u0005\r\n");
```